# Automatically detect when storing an object with ServiceStack.Redis

Tags: events, servicestack

I am looking for a way to subscribe to events like Storing a specific object type to ServiceStack.Redis.
For example I may

```
using (var redisClient = new RedisClient())
using (var redisMyObjects = redisClient.As<MyObject>())
{
        redisMyObjects.Store(myObject);//<-- I want this to trigger an event somehow
}
```

Is there anything like a OnStore event which I can hook too, anything out of the box? if not, is there any recommendation about how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything you can hook into (could be wrong).

Two options that came to mind:
1 - Make an extension method
2 - Publish a message to store your object and have a handler that listens for a response and does something. This is probably overkill since it's heading into the publish/subscribe realm. But, I think, worth looking into. ([Basic example here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-redis#example) and see [Pub/Sub here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisPubSub)).

**Extension Method**

```
public static class RedisClientExtensions
{
    public static void StoreWithTrigger<T>(this IRedisTypedClient<T> redisClient, T value, Action<T> trigger)
    {
        redisClient.Store(value);
        trigger(value);
    }
}
```

**Using ExtensionMethod**

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    using (var redisClient = new RedisClient())
    using (var redisMyObjects = redisClient.As<MyObject>())
    {
        redisMyObjects.StoreWithTrigger<MyObject>(new MyObject(), TriggerEvent);//<-- I want this to trigger an event somehow
    }
}

private void TriggerEvent<T>(T value)
{
        //dosomething
}
```

Hope this gives you some ideas.